# get location of row with median value in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row, median

I am a bit stuck with this basic problem, but I cannot find a solution.

I have two data frames (dummies below):

```
x<- data.frame("Col1"=c(1,2,3,4), "Col2"=c(3,3,6,3))
y<- data.frame("ColA"=c(0,0,9,4), "ColB"=c(5,3,20,3))
```

I need to use the location of the median value of one column in df x to then retrieve a value from df y. For this, I am trying to get the row number of the median value in e.g. `x$Col1` to then retrieve the value using something like `y[,"ColB"][row.number]`

is there an elegant way/function for doing this? Solutions might need to account for two cases - when the sample has an even number of values, and ehwn this is uneven (when numbers are even, the median value might be one that is not found in the sample as a result of calculating the mean of [the two values in the middle](https://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/vol8/median))

Comment: What result do you want when the median of x is not a value in x?

Comment: I think the best would be the row number of the lower value in the pair. @JosephClarkMcIntyre

Comment: I think you can take IceCreamToucan's reponse, just sort the dataset first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a little underspecified.

- What should happen when the median isn't in the data?
- What should happen if the median appears in the data multiple times?

Here's a solution which takes the (absolute) difference between each value and the median, then returns the index of the *first* row for which that difference vector achieves its minimum.

```
with(x, which.min(abs(Col1 - median(Col1))))
# [1] 2
```

The `quantile` function with `type = 1` (i.e. no averaging) may also be of interest, depending on your desired behavior. It returns the lower of the two "sides" of the median, while the `which.min` method above can depend on the ordering of your data.

```
quantile(x$Col1, .5, type = 1)
# 50% 
#   2
```

An option using `quantile` is

```
with(x, which(Col1 == quantile(Col1, .5, type = 1)))
# [1] 2
```

This could possibly return multiple row-numbers.

Edit: 
 If you want it to only return the first match, you could modify it as shown below

```
with(x, which.min(Col1 != quantile(Col1, .5, type = 1)))
```

Comment: You are right - and I had not thought of the second situation. I will add details timely.

Comment: From what you are saying, I am assuming that `quantile` does not require a previous sorting of the data?

Comment: Hi @IceCreamToucan - Thank you for the quick answer! I changed the code to select the maximum value, for the sake of being conservative.

Answer (score 1):

Here, something like `y$ColB[which(x$Col1 == round(median(x$Col1)))]` would do the trick.

The problem is `x` has an even number of rows, so the median `2.5` is not an integer. In this case you have to choose between `2` or `3`.

Note: The above works for your example, not for general cases (e.g. `c(-2L,2L)` or with rational numbers). For the more general case see @IceCreamToucan's solution.